# Grouping features in a data frame based on events

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, group-by, data-science

I have a user event dataframe with following information,

```
USER    Timestamp   day_of_week Busi_days   Busi_hours
AAS 2017-07-11 09:31:44 Tuesday True    True
AAS 2017-07-11 23:24:43 Tuesday True    False
SAP 2017-07-11 11:29:40 Tuesday True    True
SAP 2017-07-11 16:58:49 Tuesday True    True
YAS 2017-07-11 15:26:57 Tuesday True    True
```

And What I need to compute is certain features like, which of the USERS are `highly active` what I know is,the number of clicks, as,

```
df.groupby(['USER']).count()

USER ts     Timestamp       day_of_week Busi_days   Busi_hours
AAS 7   2017-07-11 09:31:44 Tuesday True    True
AAS 11  2017-07-11 23:24:43 Tuesday True    False
SAP 9   2017-07-11 11:29:40 Tuesday True    True
SAP 14  2017-07-11 16:58:49 Tuesday True    True
YAS 8   2017-07-11 15:26:57 Tuesday True    True
```

Now I need help or suggestions how can I best define rules  and logic   to  compute each feature `highly active`. I tried ranking as using,

```
df.groupby(['USER'])['Timestamp'].rank("dense", ascending=False),
```

which throwing value error: 
then `qcut` was another choice,

```
TA_log[['USER', 'Timestamp']].groupby(['USER']).count().apply(lambda x: pd.qcut(x, np.linspace(0,7)))
```

its throwing index error,

```
IndexError: ('index 294117 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 257354', 'occurred at index ts')
```

Any help would be great

Comment: `df.groupby(['uuid'])['ts'].rank("dense", ascending=False),` is there a column `uuid` in your dataframe?

Comment: uuid is USER in original dataframe, I edited my question

Comment: `df.groupby(['USER']).count()` does not return the results you say it does. Where does the column `ts` come from? Without that column, the rest of your code does not run.

Comment: ts was typo now edited